# Access data from hard bricked device

Tags: htc, htc-one

This question is related to previous one I asked [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164249/htc-one-m8-unfortunately-your-data-is-corrupt?newreg=2e51c8b8f5b848529fc969f2066ee8f7).

I have no hopes that I can get my phone up and working again. It is bricked. My whole effort is now about saving my data.

So my question is can I access as an external storage if I attach to my PC using a USB connection recover my data?

Comment: Your device had root access, and USB Debugging enabled? If not it's propably no chance to access your data. Any kind of encryption was enabled? If yes it's propably no chance to access your data.

Comment: No root access and no USB debugging enabled. I never encrypted it too. But mysteriously it asks me password to decrypt it.

Comment: On the phone or computer?  I wouldn't expect any reaction from a hard-bricked device?